# Will the CronJob declared `resources.request` parameters occupy resources when pod is not active?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

Will the CronJob declared `resources.request` parameters occupy resources when the pod is not active?

Answer (score 1):

When you specify the resource request for containers in a Pod, the scheduler uses this information to decide which node to place the Pod on. So if the pod is not scheduled at all then it will not use any memory.